# Stretching image and not keeping aspect ratio

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am displaying an image via PyQt in a QLabel `self.dlg.image_label` object. The result of the image is stretching and not keeping the aspect ratio while I resize the widget. What I want is that the image can resize while keeping the aspect ratio.

```
pixmap = QPixmap('path/to/image.jpg')
pixmap = pixmap.scaled(256, 256, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
self.dlg.image_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
self.dlg.image_label.setScaledContents(True)
self.dlg.image_label.show()
```

Here are the results when I stretch the widget:

[image]
[image]

Comment: QLabel doesn't provide such a feature (`setScaledContents()` only adapts the image to the size, without considering aspect ratio). If you want to achieve such result, you need a custom widget, but its usage partially depends on how you're creating your UI, so, please share a [mre].